# Submit form from Angular Dialog Template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to submit form from dialog but  `form.value` is `null`. I dont know what is missing.. I provide some  code and [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-material-dialog-watw58) as your reference.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
</div>

  <ng-template #callAPIDialog>
        <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSend(form.value)">
        <h2 matDialogTitle>Add Organization</h2>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="organisationName" placeholder="Your organization" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="enabled" [(value)]="Y" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          </mat-form-field>
        <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
            <button mat-button matDialogClose="no">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" mat-button matDialogClose="yes">Submit</button>
        </mat-dialog-actions>
    </form>
    </ng-template>
```

**COmponent**

```
openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callAPIDialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result !== undefined) {
            if (result !== 'no') {
              const enabled = "Y"
                console.log(result);
            } else if (result === 'no') {
               console.log('User clicked no.');
            }
        }
    })
}


onSend(form: NgForm){
  let data = form.value;
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: as i can see you have many errors in console first try to resolve them

Comment: ok thanks. I will fix it

Comment: ok i am trying to solve it

Comment: Please have a look at my approach may be its help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-material-dialog-rxufmu

1. I have found that your form inputs are on valid format. Please go through below link once:
    https://dzone.com/articles/template-driven-forms-in-angular
2. In submit button remove matDialogClose property keep it as simple button and while submitting data check for form valid status and all other validations which you want to apply on your inputs if all correct than close dialog else display errors
3. in ngSubmit pass whole form instead of values so that you can keep track on form status and other properties as well so do like this

   ```
   (ngSubmit)="onSend(userForm)"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get the form values. You can also close the matdialog once you submit the form. Just make few changes in the **app.component.ts** file

I have made dialogRef variable at class level and you can access that in the onSend method to close the dialog.

```js
import { Component,Input, TemplateRef, Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl, NgForm, Validators,  FormBuilder, FormGroup  } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: AppComponent}   
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('callAPIDialog') callAPIDialog: TemplateRef<any>; 
  @ViewChild('userForm') userForm: any;
  dialogRef: any;
  userModel: any = {};
  //name = 'Angular';
  
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
  
   }

  openDialog() {

    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callAPIDialog);
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(this.userForm);
        if (result !== undefined) {
            if (result !== 'no') {
              const enabled = "Y"
                console.log(result);
            } else if (result === 'no') {
               console.log('User clicked no.');
            }
        }
    })
}


onSend(form: NgForm){
  let data = form.value;
  console.log('form submitted');
  console.log(this.userModel);
  this.dialogRef.close();
}

}
```

```html
<div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
</div>

  <ng-template #callAPIDialog>
        <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSend(userForm)">
        <h2 matDialogTitle>Add Organization</h2>
       
            <input   [(ngModel)]="userModel.organisationName" placeholder="Your organization" name="organisationName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="userModel.enabled" [(value)]="Y" name="enabled" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          
        <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
            <button mat-button matDialogClose="no">Cancel</button>
            <!-- <button type="submit" mat-button matDialogClose="yes">Submit</button> -->
              <button type="submit" mat-button>Submit</button>
        </mat-dialog-actions>
    </form>
 
    </ng-template>
```